# Ruby on Rails: way to access information in linkage table using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, linker

Is there a built in method for accessing data in a linker table through the ActiveRecord framework?  I have a number of tables linked through many-to-many connections, where (ideally) information about the link should be stored in the linkage table.

For example, I have the three tables

```
create_table :diseases do |t|
    t.integer id
    t.string  name
end

create_table :pathogens do |t|
    t.integer id
    t.string  name
end

create_table :disease_pathogens do |t|
    t.integer :disease_id,  :null => false
    t.integer :pathogen_id, :null => false
    t.float   :probability
end
```

With classes defined like

```
class Disease < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :disease_pathogen
    has_mahy :pathogens, :through => :disease_pathogens
end

class Pathogen < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :disease_pathogen
    has_many :disease, :through => :disease_pathogen
end

class DiseasePathogen < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :disease
    belongs_to :pathogen
end
```

Where the linkage table gives the probability that a disease was caused by that pathogen.  Is there a way to get at that information in a straightforward way?  Now, if I have an instance of Disease d, I can find the associated by calling d.pathogens.  Is there an easy way to get at the value of probability for that relationship?  I'd love an interface like that makes reading and writing that attribute a bit more straightforward without having to write specific get_ and set_ methods, especially since I know that doing it in raw sql would be straightforward.

My very ideal interface would allow interactions of the form:

```
d = Disease.first
d.pathogens << Pathogen.create(:name => "xx", :probability => 0.12)
d.pathogens[0].probability
```

and the like.  Surely this has to be something that has come up before, but I haven't been able to find any information on it.  Or maybe I'm just trying to do something that's outside of ruby's conventions?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `probability`, at least in the given definition of the models, is not an attribute of `Pathogen` and you want to access it as though it were.

Trying to do things like `d.pathogens << Pathogen.create(:name => "xx", :probability => 0.12)` is usually not a good idea because you're combining the idea of a `DiseasePathogen` object into a `Pathogen` object. Either the two concepts are separate enough to merit their own model classes, or they're not.

If diseases and pathogens do not have an inherent probability, then the link between them is clearly important in its own right. The code will reflect that:

```
d = Disease.first
p = Pathogen.create(:name => 'xx')
l = DiseasePathogen.create(:disease => d, :pathogen => p, :probability => 0.12)
```

The last line of your ideal interface has a similar problem, but the fix is a little more complex.

When you say `d.pathogens[0]`, you're not referring to a relationship, but only to a specific `Pathogen` object that could belong to any number of `Disease` objects. That bare object has no way of knowing what link to which you're referring. That's the whole point of the `DiseasePathogen` objects.

Using `d.disease_pathogens[0].probability` will work the way you intended. Otherwise, you can create a helper function in the main classes that will provide a nice alias to this functionality.

The bottom line is that when you want to reference data stored in a certain object (in this case an object linking two other objects), you need to uniquely specify that object somehow. If you don't want to do that, you'll have to place the desired data in one of the other objects.

The best way I can come up with to mimic the interface you desire is a custom function in `Disease` and `Pathogen` that accepts an object of the complementary class and looks up the desired probability.

Comment: Hey, thanks.  I realize now that the way I was going about it probably wasn't the most logical.  I somehow missed all the documentation on the join method which makes what I want to do much easier than I thought it was.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of:

```
p = d.disease_pathogens.where(:pathogen_id => d.pathogens[0].id).first.probability
```

If you wrap it into a function, it won't look too bad.